# Wrong output language Azure Text-To-Speech

Tags: javascript, azure, sdk, text-to-speech

I use the javascript speech SDK of azure and I modified the [`speechSynthesisLanguage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechconfig?view=azure-node-latest#microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk-speechconfig-speechsynthesislanguage) property to change the output language but it does not work. The output language is still english. I followed the documentation and use the demo code available on [their repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/quickstart/javascript/node/text-to-speech/index.js).

```
(function() {
  // <code>
  "use strict";
  
  // pull in the required packages.
  var sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
  var readline = require("readline");
  const { exec } = require("child_process");
  
  // replace with your own subscription key,
  // service region (e.g., "westus"), and
  // the name of the file you save the synthesized audio.
  var subscriptionKey = "xxx";
  var serviceRegion = "francecentral"; // e.g., "westus"
  var filename = "test1.wav";

  // we are done with the setup

  // now create the audio-config pointing to our stream and
  // the speech config specifying the language.
  var audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(filename);
  var speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, serviceRegion);

  speechConfig.setProperty('speechSynthesisLanguage', 'fr-FR')
  speechConfig.setProperty('SpeechServiceConnection_RecoLanguage', 'fr-FR')
  speechConfig.setProperty('speechSynthesisVoiceName', 'fr-FR-AlainNeural')
  console.log(speechConfig)
  
  //create the speech synthesizer.
  var synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);


  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  rl.question("Test à saisir :\n", function (text) {
    rl.close();
    // start the synthesizer and wait for a result.
    synthesizer.speakTextAsync(text,
        function (result) {
      if (result.reason === sdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
        console.log("synthesis finished.");
      } else {
        console.error("Speech synthesis canceled, " + result.errorDetails +
            "\nDid you update the subscription info?");
      }
      synthesizer.close();
      synthesizer = undefined;
    },
        function (err) {
      console.trace("err - " + err);
      synthesizer.close();
      synthesizer = undefined;
    });
    console.log("Now synthesizing to: " + filename);
    exec(`vlc ${filename} vlc://quit`);
  });
  // </code>
  
}());
```

The output language is corretly set to `fr-FR` [according to the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/language-support?tabs=stt-tts).

```
console.log(speechConfig.getProperty('speechSynthesisLanguage')) //fr-FR
```

I tried to change the language by german or use the [`setServiceProperty(string, string, ServicePropertyChannel)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechconfig?view=azure-node-latest#microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk-speechconfig-setserviceproperty) method but it didn't work.

Do you have a solution? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I am assuming you want to convert French text into speech which will be French. Now to do this we need to set two setting i.e `speechSynthesisLanguage` and `speechSynthesisVoiceName`  these settings would represent name of the language you are passing and name of the speech.
- Here I was created a function which will ask for French as text and will add the data to the `YourAudioFile.wav` file.

code:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var  sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
var  readline = require("readline");

  

var  audioFile = "YourAudioFile.wav";

const  speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(process.env.SPEECH_KEY, process.env.SPEECH_REGION);
const  audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(audioFile);

  // the speech settings for french

speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = "fr-FR";

speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "fr-FR-BrigitteNeural";

var  synthesizer = new  sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
var  rl = readline.createInterface({
    input:  process.stdin,
    output:  process.stdout
});

 
rl.question("Enter some text that you want to speak >\n> ", 
        function (text)
        {
            rl.close();
            synthesizer.speakTextAsync(text,
                function (result) 
                {
                    if (result.reason === sdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                        {
                            console.log("synthesis finished.");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            console.error("Speech synthesis canceled, " + result.errorDetails +"\nDid you set the speech resource key and region values?");
                        }
                    synthesizer.close();
                    synthesizer = null;
                },
            function (err) 
            {
                console.trace("err - " + err);
                synthesizer.close();        
                synthesizer = null;
            }
        );
        console.log("Now synthesizing to: " + audioFile);
        }
    );
}());
```

The majority of the above code is from this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=windows,terminal&pivots=programming-language-javascript) on text to speech.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It allowed me to find out that the documentation was not clear.
In the documentation the properties are called `speechSynthesisLanguage` and `speechSynthesisVoiceName` but in fact, if you want to modify them with the `setProperty()` method, their names are not the same. They are respectively `SpeechServiceConnection_SynthLanguage` and `SpeechServiceConnection_SynthVoice`.
In fact, `speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = "en-FR"` is equal to `speechConfig.setProperty('SpeechServiceConnection_SynthLanguage', 'en-FR')`.
Thanks a lot for your help.